# MSI Dragon Center stuck on "Waiting for SDK Loading" but SDK is missing

Tags: windows-10, gpu

**Original Question:** I regularly use MSI's Dragon Center software to help me manage my custom PC build. If you go to Home > User Scenario > Custom, it will show you the currently installed GPU. I recently installed a different variant of the same graphics card and it has not updated to show the new version. How would one go about forcing an update or a re-poll of the hardware?

Side note: the old card had no LEDs or fancy doodads whereas the new one is Mystic Light compatible but it does not show up in the Home > Mystic Light screen.

Perused through DC's install directory but had no file that stood out as a system information log that could be deleted to force a rescan.

**Edit:** @Ramhound was correct in that deleting all the registry keys would help - however that is not entirely accurate. This is a bit of a strange and particular use-case. Swapping a base level variant of the GPU out for a higher-tier variant of the same card, both manufactured by MSI.

At first the question was just what I needed, I only needed a way to force an update to show the new card. I however accidentally screwed up my machine by doing a somewhat messy uninstall of MSI's Dragon Center. I then spent the next 6 hours and another 8 hours the next day trying to figure out how to get it to re-install.

So for anyone who is stuck with the same problem I had for the past 12+ hours where you could go to Settings > Apps > Dragon Center > Uninstall and then re-download and install from the Microsoft Store only to get stuck on "Waiting for SDK loading" the fix is in the answer.

Comment: Sounds like the software is only designed to detect versions released by MSI.  You probably will have to uninstall and delete all registry keys that refers to the version you installed and explicitly only use the version Dragon Center offered

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It helped push me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Alright - so I'll try to be thorough in my answer.

I couldn't find anyone else who had this problem even after multiple hours of searching various search engines. Most people had a problem with "Waiting on SDK Initialization" which is different (most had the problem with MSI Central Service not starting and that fixed that) but my problem was that the installer thought the first step (of two) was completed when in actuality it was not.

The installer has 2 different steps at the beginning:

1. "Waiting on SDK Installing"
2. "Waiting on SDK Loading"

In step 1 is where it will install multiple parts of Dragon Center that are all sort of "contained" within the SDK. This was where it was failing. It would briefly show the "Waiting on SDK Installing" and then almost immediately switch to "Waiting on SDK Loading" without performing anything that was actually supposed to be completed in step 1.

The SDK cannot be downloaded separately for Custom Desktop PCs - you can find forums where there is a link to download the SDK but those I've found were actually for complete MSI prebuilds or laptops which wouldn't work in my case.

So to fix this I found that when the installer timed out it would give me a screen that said something along the lines of "Please make sure the MSI software service is not blocked by Anti-Virus, Firewall or other applications." and then it had a link directly under labelled "Click here for service list."

This prints out a long list of all the MSI Services that were to be installed, where they were to be installed, where their executable should live, and where their registry key resides.

I decided to do an uninstall through the Settings > App screen, reboot, and then check the registry to see if those registry entries had been deleted. Lo and behold they had not so I went through and deleted every registry entry I could find that referenced "One Dragon Center". There were a few that I could not delete but after deleting them all, doing a reboot, and then running the installer as admin, it realized the SDK was not installed and installed Dragon Center properly.

TL;DR

- uninstall dragon center through the Windows Settings App
- reboot
- delete all registry keys referencing "One Dragon Center"
- reboot
- install Dragon Center from Microsoft Store
- run Dragon Center as administrator
- fixed